# Activity is not waiting for alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am actually a C# developer but currently developing an app for an android with java.

Well,I wanted to create a general dialog alert class and has a static method that is given title,message as parameter and shows an alert. it seems everything OK. Here is the my class..

```
public class AlertDialogHelper  {

public static void setOkMessage(Context context,String title,String message)
{

    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

             // NOTHING??

        }
    });     

    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    dialog.show();
 }
}
```

and I called this static method in my splashactivity, but when alert dialog appeared, after code is going on that means execute codes below..

```
private void closeSplashActivity() {

 Intent activity;
 boolean isNew=true;

  try{

    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    dbHelper.openDbConnection();
    isNew = dbHelper.getSettings(DbContext.COLUMN_ISNEW);
    dbHelper.closeDbConnection();

   if (isNew)
   AlertDialogHelper.setOkMessage(this, "XXX", "YYYY");

   else
       AlertDialogHelper.setOkMessage(this, "XXXXX", "YYYYY");



 } catch (Exception ex) {

AlertDialogHelper.setOkMessage(this, "Error", "XXXXX:" + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
 }

   if(isNew) 
   activity = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ChooseQualityActivity.class); 

   else 
   activity = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);

   startActivity(activity);
   finish();

 }
```

Normally, It must wait for the onclick event and after that

```
    if(isNew) 
   activity = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ChooseQualityActivity.class);
```

must work.. but, it doesnt wait and run this code above.. So, I do not know what I can do it for it.. And Is there another method for creating general dialog box? Because it looks so long code to create for each message.

@Edit..

I have just realized that some exception in logcat

> 01-30 23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191): Activity
>   com.aaa.bbbb.SplashActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2c12e008
>   V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-348,285} that was originally added here 01-30
>   23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191): android.view.WindowLeaked:
>   Activity com.aaa.bbbb.SplashActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2c12e008
>   V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-348,285} that was originally added here 01-30
>   23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:354) 01-30
>   23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):  at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
>   01-30 23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):    at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   01-30 23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):    at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281) 01-30 23:07:47.375:
>   E/WindowManager(9191):    at
>   com.aaa.bbbb.utility.AlertDialogHelper.setOkMessage(AlertDialogHelper.java:31)
>   01-30 23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):    at
>   com.aaa.bbbb.SplashActivity.closeSplashActivity(SplashActivity.java:65)
>   01-30 23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):    at
>   com.aaa.bbbb.SplashActivity.access$0(SplashActivity.java:53) 01-30
>   23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):  at
>   com.aaa.bbbb.SplashActivity$1.onCompletion(SplashActivity.java:40)
>   01-30 23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):    at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1980)
>   01-30 23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-30
>   23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 01-30 23:07:47.375:
>   E/WindowManager(9191):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 01-30
>   23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-30
>   23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 01-30 23:07:47.375:
>   E/WindowManager(9191):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   01-30 23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 01-30
>   23:07:47.375: E/WindowManager(9191):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I think you have to pass a callback method. And where you have "Nothing?" Then you have to make call the callback method. In the standard Dialog behavior it'll execute the code inside the OnClick method after the user interaction.

Comment: I thought the same but I haven't found anything to do something like callback.. could you give me a sample for it?. and thank you for your answer @hmartinezd

Comment: @hmartinezd, i wrote dialog.dismiss() on the onclick event but its the same, and i edited my question and put logcat messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first you have to define an interface like this:

```
interface MyCallback {
    void callbackCall();
}
```

Then in your AlertDialogHelper class include a member, like this:

```
MyCallback mCallback;
```

I your set OkMessageMethod add a parameter

```
public static void setOkMessage(Context context,String title,String message, MyCallback callback) {
mCallback = callback
```

later in onClick method you call like this:

```
callback.callbackCall();
```

the rest is easy, just call the setOkMessage this way:

```
AlertDialogHelper.setOkMessage(this, "Error", "XXXXX:" + ex.getMessage(), new MyCallback(){
 // Here the code you want to execute after the click event
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much :) it helped me much. I changed a bit your code, because it needed unimplemented method bla bla.. but now I tried it and everything seems fine. thank you again :))